# Gemfire versus BigMemory Go

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Can Gemfire be used like Big Memory Go as a L2 cache provider with hibernate? Using hibernate XML files , not annotations. If an applications uses lots of redundant hibernate calls, trying to see if Gemfire could integrate as a L2 cache to use as a off heap solution for caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to Pivotal GemFire 9.0.x (e.g. Pivotal GemFire 8.2.x and earlier) GemFire had support for Hibernate L2 Cache; see [here](http://gemfire82.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/tools_modules/hibernate_cache/chapter_overview.html).

However, this was pulled in Pivotal GemFire 9 due to a lack of support on maintaining the feature and keeping it up-to-date with the latest versions of Hibernate.

SIDE NOTE:

I am not sure if you are aware of this... but Pivotal GemFire was released to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) as the [Apache Geode open source project](http://geode.apache.org/) (April, 2015) and became a TLP last year (~October 2016).  Therefore, Apache Geode is the open source core for Pivotal GemFire, especially as of [Pivotal GemFire 9.0](https://pivotal.io/pivotal-gemfire).

I mention this because the work/code is not lost, it is mostly a WIP.  See...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-1972

I see that the feature branch (i.e. `feature/GEODE-1972`) does NOT exist yet.

There was discussion about this on the Geode dev list...

http://apache.markmail.org/thread/uvuzoohkfplkg46u

So, it probably just needs some "interests", maybe even some help/contributions from the community to move this along.  A good opportunity to get involved and have an impact.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Surprised they would want to remove hibernate feature as this would be a common use case for ORM to have a L2 caching solution. Looks like bigmemory go would be the more appropriate solution that is less intrusive.

Comment: Well, they removed it temporarily until they can get it back up to snuff and on par with the latest version of Hibernate.  I would say you should use the solution that best fits your problem and keeps it as simple as possible (i.e. less is more).  Good luck!